# MongoDB 3.6 with PHP 7.4: unknown operator $text

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
 $connection = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
  $db = "db";
  $coll = "calls";
  $filter = [];
  $options= [];
  $coll = "calls";
  $Client= "linux";
  $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(['count' => $coll, 'query' => ['Client' => ['$text' => ['$search' => $Client]]]]);
  $result = $connection->executeCommand($db,$query);
  $res = current($result->toArray());
  $countAll = $res->n;
  echo ("Total linux clients \"Unknown\": " . $countAll . "\n");
```

Why does this script throw an error that $text operator is unknown? if I use $gt or $eq on some other field but in the same syntax, they work. Just $text won't.

The goal is to count documents that have Client field with contents "linux" (e.g *linux-1*, *linux0.7* etc).

Comment: You did not define the $text variable that is returning a string, should it not be just 'text'? If you did define $text somewhere, use $text without the apostrophes ' '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) performs a text search on the content of the fields indexed with a text index.

You can not use `$text` on a specific field. If you use `$text`, MongoDB will search through all fields that is text indexed.

So your command shouldn't include `Client`

```
['count' => $coll, 'query' => ['$text' => ['$search' => $Client]]]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but only when a field's value is equal to $Client value. But I need partial search. So when $Client = "SiDock" I need results when there's value "SiDock", "SiDock1334", "SiDockABC". How do I do that? And is there a way (for the future) to change my code so I can say: "where Client field has *sometext" inside the string". In sql it would be >where Client like "%sometext%"<.

Comment: Check out [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/), with `$regex`, you can query a specific field like to tried earlier. Also check out [this article](https://medium.com/statuscode/how-to-speed-up-mongodb-regex-queries-by-a-factor-of-up-to-10-73995435c606)